# How would one interpret: "must not exceed X and Y" vs "must not exceed X and not exceed Y"

Tags: grammar, logic

**EDIT/NOTE: This phrase is from a legal document, so rules of plain language / literal interpretation are assumed to apply, so please refrain from assuming what you believe was intended by the writer. THIS IS NOT A LEGAL QUESTION, but one about proper grammatical logic. It would be highly appreciated if you referenced English grammar rules to support your point.**

I've been debating with someone over the correct grammatical interpretation of the following sentence:

> Structure must not exceed 12 feet by 12 feet base **and** 12 feet in height.

I am fairly convinced this means the structure must exceed **both** base and height dimensions in order to fail to meet the requirement. *However they argue* if the structure exceeds **either** base or height dimensions, then it will fail to meet the requirement.

- Here are the two ways this could be logically interpreted, both returning opposite results:

  > H = 10, B = 20
  >
  > not (H > 12 and B > 12) ------> True
  >
  > not H > 12 and not B > 12 ------> False

I believe my interpretation is correct since there is only a single "not exceed", as well as no commas in the sentence. Whereas if the sentence said "not exceed ... and not exceed..", then that would follow the second logic:

> Structure must not exceed (12 feet by 12 feet base and 12 feet in height) ------> True
>
> Structure must (not exceed 12 feet by 12 feet base) and (not exceed 12 feet in height) ------> False

Furthermore, if the sentence used an "or" instead of "and", then that would mean that exceeding **either** constraint would result in failure to meet the requirement:

> Structure must not exceed 12 feet by 12 feet base **or** 12 feet in height.

#### Grammatically speaking, I believe the "and" is a coordinating conjunction forming a compound object, upon which the "not exceed" is acting singularly to both objects. Is this accurate?

Comment: I don't think it needs much grammaticaI analysis: fairly sure that the requirement limits the structure's size in all dimensions, not selectively, which makes the statement unambiguous. To stretch the point, a structure which is 1 mile high won't be allowed just because its base is 11 feet by 11 feet.

Comment: [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22conjunction+reduction%22) always removes information. (As a rule it's optional, except in some fixed phrases, and it often allows several possibilities in a given sentence.) When information is removed, ambiguity is more likely. In an ambiguous sentence, the interpretation by the addressee cannot be controlled.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ELU, and thank you for an interesting and carefully thought-out question. And you have a point.  For example:-

> You should not consume wine and pork.

This is troublingly ambiguous:  it seems that as long as I refrain from one of them, I have fulfilled the requirement:  especially if we are following the rules of formal logic, according to which A&B <--> not (A and not B) {A and B implies not (A and not B)}.  Only the obvious context of Jewish and Islamic practice makes it obvious that both are forbidden.  So we had better say instead:

> You should **refrain** from wine and pork.

Now there is no possible doubt:  you cannot have either. The grammar forbids it.  But we have to remember that in the rules of propositional logic, 'A' and 'B' stand for propositions.

> Structure must not exceed 12 feet by 12 feet base and structure must not exceed 12 feet in height. or rather:  It must be the case that structure does not exceed 12 feet by 12 feet base and it must be the case that structure does not exceed 12 feet in height.

Both clauses must be true for the whole rather clumsy disambiguated sentence to be true.  Negatives present a minefield of ambiguity.  You have smartly prevented answerers from resorting to common sense to say that it is obvious, in the context of building permits that both height and footprint are subject to the scale limit.

You are also right to say that the conventional way round this logical ambiguity is to use the disjunction 'or'  However, even this does not remove ambiguity, as 'not A or B' means 'not A implies B'.  So we have to have '**neither** A **nor** B'.  In other words, to prevent any possibility of ambiguity we should have to say:

> Structure must not exceed **either** 12 feet by 12 feet base **or** 12 feet in height.

I wish all writers paid the attention to univocality that you are paying.  However, sadly attention to precision of meaning seems to be in decline.  And grammar, as a system of classifying what people actually do must sooner or later follow usage, which is, after all the the key final word of ELU.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'd also like to point out that the example I gave in my post was from a legal code, which inherently necessitates unambiguous wording, and it is typically the case for legal documents to use redundant wording for clarity. As well, in the mentioned document, there are no context clues that would clarify it, as there would be in the bible, like you mentioned.

Comment: If it were really true that legal code were inherently and necessarily unambiguous then large numbers of lawyers would be out of work. When real life ambiguities occur in legal documentation the courts look at the whole context, not just a sentence in isolation. That is important in this case since the OP says that other parts of the document bear on the dimensions.

Comment: @JeremyC I didn't say that legal code is never ambiguous, just that the expectation is for it to be unambiguous - or rather, the expectation is for it to be interpreted in plain language. In legal situations, courts are expected to interpret statutes in plain english with minimal assumption, and only resort to their own interpretation if that plain interpretation ends up being overly absurd or non-sensible. Also I am OP- the mention about other restrictions in the document was to point out that the plain-language interpretation was not "absurd", ie, wouldn't allow a 1000000x1000000x11 building

Comment: @JeremyC Yes, if the legal writing has failed to be or been unable to be unambiguous, context has to be taken into account.  But how it should be taken into account is often disputed as in the US right to bear arms.  The aim, nevertheless, clarity.

Comment: @John One thing we learn is that in legal documents avoid negatives if at all possible, and that where they are necessary, spell it all out in full, however tedious.

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous, there is not a answer which will determine if the correct interpretation is

- must not exceed both X and Y
- must not exceed at least one of X or Y

It if comes from legal code, then the only source of truth is case law depending on your jurisdiction, or a legal judgement.

Comment: It should be noted there is a difference between social ambiguity (what is reasonably expected), and grammatical/plain language ambiguity. The phrase has social ambiguity, but not plain language ambiguity. Interpreting it in plain language with no/minimal assumption leads to a single explicit interpretation. In legal situations, the standard is to interpret the plain language, and only if that plain language sounds absurd would the court resort to its own interpretation.

Comment: Here is a paper on legal drafting dealing with the ambiguities of using "and" and "or".

https://adamsdrafting.com/downloads/Ambiguity-And-Or.pdf

In section IV.B this situation is handled explicitly.

In the paper, the analysis is that the "more natural" interpretation of "must not exceed X and Y" is that there are two requirements, "must not exceed X" and "must not exceed Y".


Also it says that if the intended meaning is "must not exceed X and Y but may exceed one of them" that you should not rely on "must not exceed X and Y" to do so.

Comment: This is a good paper on the ambiguity of wording, however as you mentioned, it is dealing with legal drafting, not interpretation. The people who wrote the example I gave in my OP should have referred to this document to achieve more clarity. When it comes to legal interpretation, the only time courts can diverge from the plain-language/literal interpretation is when said interpretation happens to be overly absurd, which in this case it is not.

Comment: It seems you are not asking an English language question but a legal question, and as I understand it the law and caselaw is ambiguous about the answer as well.  If you really need an answer ask a lawyer or go to court.  It also seems that you are not really asking a question but looking to confirm your position and the only answer you would accept was one that agreed with your interpretation.

Comment: I have to disagree on both points. I asked a question and presented my evidence/research for my view, and then I asked people what the grammatically correct interpretation was based on English grammar rules. Most of the replies have not included any references to grammar rules, thus I've had to repeatedly stress that this is what the focus is. The only relevance the law/court has to the discussion was to point out that they just happen to be an entity which relies upon strict grammar interpretation, whereas social norms do not. This is not at all a legal question, but one of grammar.

Comment: (cont.) I also do not believe I am only looking to confirm my position. The reason I have not accepted the other answers, and have responded/debated with them, is because most of the replies have not made any reference to grammar rules as I requested. I very much welcome any response which counters mine and uses grammar rules to prove their point).

Comment: @John You were already told that conjunctions can present [gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics)#Gapping_or_not?) (although they used the name conjunction reduction). This means that *must not exceed* could be either part of the constituents of the conjunction (being gaped from the second constituent)  or could be outside of the conjunction if one assumes that no gaping has occurred. Therefore, the sentence is inherently ambiguous, while still properly formed.

Comment: @mama The sentence IS ambiguous socially, but grammatically it has a single function. There is a single subject, a verb portion, and a compound object formed by virtue of the conjunction "and". However as mentioned, social context rarely follows strict grammatical rules, and is dependent on assumptions based on social context like you mentioned.

Comment: @John You simply don't know what you are talking about. The sentence is ambiguous because the same syntactical structure can be parsed in several ways, even after you assign a unique meaning to each of its tokens. The grammatical rules allow to parse it either assuming that gaping was used or assuming that it didn't.

Comment: @mama You keep bringing up social conventions (assumption of gapped words), when I stated I was focusing purely on the as-is grammatical interpretation. You say the sentence can be parsed in several ways even after assigning meaning to its tokens, but I don't see how - can you give examples (without assuming gapped words)? There's a subject, "structure", verb group, "must not exceed", and the compound object, base&height and it's adjectives. How can these three SVO components act on each other in more than a single grammatical manner with the words given?

Comment: @John Gaping is a syntactical construction. You are qualifying things as "social convention" because you don't know what is what. Everything is a social convention, even formal languages. It is the same as when the C++ standard describes the compilation of some constructions as *undefined behavior*. Compilers can do whatever they want in those cases. In the same way, conjunctions in English can or not present gaping. Therefore, when you read it you can choose to read it with or without it.

Comment: @mama I never said gapping was a social convention, I said "assumption" was. In either case, you seem to have ignored what I wrote in my initial question, when I clearly stated I was asking about plain language interpretation without assuming what the author wrote. The "not assuming" part was an extremely core part to my question, and a core part of plain language interpretation (which is a very well established concept).

Comment: @John It is you who doesn't understand the answer. There is no such thing as "plain language interpretation". There are "plain language interpretationS". And that is what I and everyone is telling you. But you imagine for some reason that that cannot be, even though that happens in absolutely all languages, from natural languages such as English, to formal languages.

Comment: @mama Please point out where anyone has referred to other systems of plain language interpretation. Keep in mind that the entire point of "plain language interpretation" is to interpret without assuming any missing words.

Comment: @John You must read the links that you were given. You have already all the information that you need to understand the answer. If you don't then that is because the answer is not within your sphere of understanding. You need more instruction. Gaping is not about adding or not words to a sentence, is about how a single sentence is parsed. You keep thinking under the assumption that for a given sentence there is a canonical way to assign meaning to it. That is wrong. There is nothing else that I need to add for you to understand. It is you who needs to go a read and learn.

Comment: @mama Plain meaning/language interpretation by definition involves interpreting words in the most literal way, with the most common meaning, with the most basic grammar logical rules, and with minimal assumption, which highly *restricts* flexibility in parsing. I have not seen anyone present an alternative way this sentence can be parsed under such rules. FYI, the link you gave for gapping literally refers to it as an ellipsis mechanism, which by definition refers to the omission of words that would be understood(assumed) in context, and that is directly opposite of literal interpretation.

Comment: @John Ellipsis is a syntactical construction which sometimes is optional and sometimes obligatory (like comparative deletion). In both cases, the assignation of meaning is done by adding back the particle omitted. This is done because in the case of natural language there is no other way to convey meaning than to use natural language again. That doesn't mean that the sentence is being altered. Anyway, you still insist in your imagined world. Be happy. Don't learn how things actually are. Who cares. It is only you who remains ignorant.

Comment: @mama I literally found that definition of ellipsis directly from the link YOU provided. It's not my opinion. The definition of ellipsis according to both google and wiki (which you linked earlier) is 'the omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.' The entire point of plain language interpretation is **not** to assume the existence of "understood" words and not to infer from context. It's entire function is to minimize the number of possible interpretations, by restricting interpretation to the literal.